# Create a list of values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, csv, oracle11g

while I do understand that this does not follow best practices I am forced to come up with a strange solution.

I have been handed a CSV file with list of items, they all have just one field, and there are several hundred  non-sequential items in that file.
Ex. from CSV file :

```
item1987685
item2284321
item3098678
.....
item11248910237498
```

I need to `SELECT` records from my database that belong to that file(`field1 = ItemFromCVS`) from multiple tables.

So I am hoping to turn the CVS into a table that I can interact with in SQL(I am paraphrasing I don't have actual write access to my database), lets call it `CSV_TABLE` and extract records from my data base using data from the CSV file.

Here is an simplified example of what I need

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE field1 IN (ItemFromCVS)

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE field1 IN (ItemFromCVS)
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN CSV_TABLE
ON field1 = CSV_TABLE.ItemFromCVS

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table2
JOIN CSV_TABLE
ON field1 = CSV_TABLE.ItemFromCVS
```

Not sure if I am explaining this correctly, please let me know if you need me to clarify anything, or if you have a completely different solution. In either case what I need is a way for my SQL query to read contents of a CSV file.

Comment: Have you considered loading the CSV as an external table?

Comment: I did not know that this is possible can you elaborate?

Comment: Start with [external table concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm).